# Why is the IN statement true when it obviously shouldn't be? (lots of sense (once you know it))

Tags: python-3.x

I am making an impossibly simple piece of code to check for words in a string of inputted text but the IN is returning true when it obviously should return false and I've tested different versions of the code for a few hours and cant reason why this happens?!?

```
    >>> y= "yeh im gonna lose my mind over this"
    >>> if "screen" or "display" or "crack" or "smash" in y:
    ...     print ("Y does this happen?")
    ... 
    Y does this happen? #Output
```

EDIT: I think this question is viable and not a duplicate as it entails the information of the ordering of the IN and OR statement in a loop whereas the previous question i believe only asked for a simple answer on IN statements.

Comment: [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) is well defined in Python. There is no dark magic here, only simple _obvious_ rules applied.

Comment: yes i know, but almost all of physics was once considered magic until we came up with some thoeries! :)

Comment: @PythonGuy_InNeed FWIW I chose that question because it's our standard target for lots of questions where people not used to Python make this mistake with `or`, not because your question is literally identical. Also, I definitely recommend looking at things like `any` or something shorter than the very repetitive answer you've chosen. Imagine doing that for a list of 12 items!

Comment: @Two-Bit Alchemist Yes i do thank you for your help and will experiment with the "any" statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably not using `in` as you intended:

```
if "screen" in y or "display" in y or "crack" in y or "smash" in y
```

What you've done will always return `True` because the truthy value of a non empty string is `True`

So `if "screen"` returns `True` and no matter what the others are, the `if` always evaluates to `True`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want an [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) test here:

```
In [1]: y = "yeah I'm gonna lose my mind over this"

In [2]: if any(word in y for word in ('screen', 'display', 'crack', 'smash')):
   ...:     print('why does this happen?')
   ...: else:
   ...:     print("it doesn't ;)")
   ...:
it doesn't ;)

In [3]: if any(word in y for word in ('yeah', 'screen', 'display', 'crack', 'smash')):
   ...:     print('now it happens')
   ...:
now it happens
```

Answer (score 0):

`or` is lasily evaluated and has *lower* priority than `in` statement, which means your statement

```
if "screen" or "display" or "crack" or "smash" in y
```

evaluates to

```
if "screen" or ("display" or ("crack" or ("smash" in y)))
```

As "screen" is a true value, `or` "returns `True`" and the remaining of the condition is never evaluated.